# What can someone with malicious intent do with my Google App Signing upload key?

Tags: android, google-play, code-signing, android-app-bundle

I'm using Google Play Store App Signing and sign my app bundles with an upload key. Am I correct in assuming that when someone gets their hand on my upload key, they can actually do nothing with it as that key is not used to authenticate with the play store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, if the upload key is compromised, a third party can sign their APKs with the same key as your APKs are.

I can think of one scenario where this can lead to tangible harm. If you have multiple applications, *and* they exchange data using a private, intent-based protocol that other apps are not supposed to use, *and* you employ signature protected Android permissions to ensure that, *then* an attacker will be able to bypass that protection.

For example, if your app publishes a piece of proprietary content for your other apps to use that third party apps are not supposed to see (maybe because they haven't paid), an attacker can potentially get access to that content.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. I can't think of anything that the attacker could do with the upload key other than uploading new APKs on your behalf if he/she has access to your play store account.

The signature of the upload key is removed from any uploaded APKs before they’re sent to users as the upload key is only registered with Google to authenticate the identity of the app creator.

Remember that you can [replace your upload key](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) if it got stolen/compromised.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Your biggest threat as always is internal- a rogue employee who has the key could upload a modified version of the APK if he has access to Google Play and the authority to push new versions. The solution to that risk is to restrict the number of people who can push new versions, and to promptly revoke access to anyone who leaves the company.

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk if an account with access to your Play Console is compromised. Then if they have the upload key, they could upload an APK or App Bundle on your behalf and your users would get the new version.

With the upload key alone, not much can be done.